# Why do some Parmigiano Reggiano contain bacterial cultures?

Tags: cheese, parmesan

I was under the impression from what I have read/DOP [specification](https://www.parmigianoreggiano.com/consortium/rules_regulation_2/default.aspx) that only rennet was to be used for Parmigiano Reggiano.

`Milk coagulation, obtained exclusively by the use of calf rennet, takes place in bell-shaped copper vats; up to two wheels are made for each vat.`

Yet, I come across many Parmigiano Reggiano cheeses imported from Italy with the real Reggiano logo and the DOP symbol (e.g. [Tre Stelle](https://www.trestelle.ca/english/cheese/parmigianoreggiano), [Italissima](https://www.spud.ca/catalogue/ProductDetails.cfm?D=&M=0&W=1&OP=C37&PG=999&CG=6&S=1&G=0&Add=0&rid=0&Search=&qry=1%20eq%200&qqq2=1%20%3D%200&myPage=grocery&part=6639), [President's Choice](http://www.presidentschoice.ca/en_CA/products/productlisting/pc-splendido-parmigiano-reggiano.html), [Compliments](http://www.compliments.ca/product/parmigiano-reggiano-cheese-00623682116236/), etc.)

Is it just a loophole in the specification and found only in lower-end Parmasen Reggiano?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bacterial cultures are what the document you quoted from refers to as "fermented whey".  The previous paragraph in the Specification of the Parmigiano Reggiano Cheese from the [Parmigiano-Reggiano Cheese Consortium 
 web site](https://www.parmigianoreggiano.com/consortium/rules_regulation_2/default.aspx) reads as follows:

> Fermented whey is added to the milk, which is a natural culture of lactic ferments obtained from
>   spontaneous acidification of the whey remaining from the cheese-making process of the previous
>   day.

All Paramgiano Reggiano cheeses would have these bacterial cultures in them, not just the cheap ones.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Do some just not list it? As well, the President's Choice I linked above has lysoszyme, so still a mystery on that.

Comment: @AdamThompson I'd guess the absence of bacterial cultures in the ingredient list is an oversight. Apparently virtually all Grana Padano cheese uses lysoszyme as a preservative so it appearing on the ingredient list on the web site might just be a cut and paste error.